# Conditionally set data frame values based on logic

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, multiple-columns, back-testing

I have a data frame that has price of an asset, a bunch of trigger prices and some price target parameters.

```
target_A = +2
target_B = -1

                         price    trigger  
2017-08-17 04:00:00      1        True
2017-08-17 04:01:00      2        None      
2017-08-17 04:02:00      3        None      
2017-08-17 04:03:00      5        None      
2017-08-17 04:04:00      7        True
2017-08-17 04:05:00      3        None      
2017-08-17 04:06:00      4        None      
2017-08-17 04:07:00      10       True
2017-08-17 04:08:00      11       None      
2017-08-17 04:09:00      10       None      
2017-08-17 04:10:00      11       None      
2017-08-17 04:10:00      11       True
2017-08-17 04:11:00      10       None      
2017-08-17 04:12:00      12       None      
2017-08-17 04:13:00      11       None
```

```
Desired Output:

target_A = +2
target_B = -1
                         price    trigger  target_A         target_B 
2017-08-17 04:00:00      1        True      3               0                
2017-08-17 04:01:00      2        None      3               0                
2017-08-17 04:02:00      3        None      Win             None             
2017-08-17 04:03:00      5        None      None            None             
2017-08-17 04:04:00      7        True      9               6                
2017-08-17 04:05:00      3        None      None            Loss             
2017-08-17 04:06:00      4        None      None            None             
2017-08-17 04:07:00      10       True      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:08:00      11       None      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:09:00      10       None      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:10:00      11       None      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:10:00      11       True      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:11:00      10       None      12              9                
2017-08-17 04:12:00      12       None      Win             None             
2017-08-17 04:13:00      11       None      None            None
```

When trigger is True, place 2 targets, a target +2 from current price and a target -1 from current price.

The aim is to see if price reaches target_A or Target_B more often.

Once the current price is either equal to or greater than the target_A or equal to or less than target_B then the the targets should display 'Win' if target_A is breached or 'Loss' if target_B is breached.

Subsequently both target_A & target_B will remain as None until another trigger price is presented.

If a target hasn't been hit yet and a another trigger price is presented then ignore this additional trigger price and continue with the previous targets.

Answer (score 1):

I converted the sample data into a csv and was able to come up with this code for counting target_A and target_B hits.

```
df = pd.read_csv('price.csv', names=['date', 'price', 'trigger'])
# cast "None" to NoneType
df['trigger'].replace({'None': None}, inplace=True)

# create columns with None as initial value
df['target_A'] = None
df['target_B'] = None

shouldTargetUpdate = True
tA, tB = None, None

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if shouldTargetUpdate and row['trigger']:
        tA = row['price'] + 2
        tB = row['price'] - 1
        shouldTargetUpdate = False   
        
    else:
        if tA is not None and row['price'] >= tA:
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_A'] = 'Win'
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_B'] = None
            tA, tB = None, None
            shouldTargetUpdate = True
            continue

        elif tB is not None and row['price'] <= tB:
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_A'] = None
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_B'] = 'Loss'
            tA, tB = None, None
            shouldTargetUpdate = True
            continue
        
    df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_A'] = tA
    df.loc[df.index[i], 'target_B'] = tB
```

To count the hits:

```
print('Price reaches target_A {} times'.format((df['target_A'] == 'Win').sum()))
print('Price reaches target_B {} times'.format((df['target_B'] == 'Loss').sum()))
```

Comment: I get this error below. Is this because my index is in date.time format?

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: yep it was, i changed the index to just numbers and its all good now! Thank you!